# adding two numbers in a session

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am doing a web application in ASP.net / C# where a random number (num1) is generated on a Page_Load event. In the web page there is a button, whenever the user clicks that button a new random number (num2) is generated and it is added (+) to the previous one in a Button_Click event. This keeps on going infinitely (keep on adding a new random number to the last addition).  I have tried using sessions I did not find a clear example. I would really appreciate your suggestions and help.

Code:

```
private static Random random = new Random();
        private int randomNumber(int min, int max)
        {
            return random.Next(min, max);
        }


        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             number1 = randomNumber(1, 10);
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int number2 = randomNumber(1, 10);
            Session["number_x"] = number2;
            number2 += number1;
        }
```

Lets say on the page_load the random number generated is 4. The user then clicks the button which generates a new random number lets say 5. Now 5 should be added to 4 = 9. If the user again clicks the button generating again a new number say 5, so now the session should have 14 and so on.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you be more clear? You want to add the addition in the session variable?

Comment: @FrancisP Please check the post after the code I have edited it

Answer (score 4):

I think you want to do something like this:

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    lock (Session.SyncRoot)
    {
       int numberInSession = (int) Session["number_x"];
       int number2 = randomNumber(1, 10);
       int newNumber = numberInSession + number2;
       Session["number_x"] = newNumber 
     }
}
```

Comment: I agree with the solution, but I think it should be newNumber = numberInSession + number2; (maybe it was a typo)

Comment: @gbanfill Please check the post after the code I have edited it

Comment: Any time that you are working with shared variables, such as the session, you need to be aware of the possibility of multiple callers. Add `lock (Session.SyncRoot) {}` to this code.

Comment: @gbanfill this shows an error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: If Session["number_x"] doesn't have anything in it yet, that `int numberInSession = (int) Session["number_x"];` will throw that error @JeT_BluE.

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm, if I'm reading your question correctly, this should work:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int number2 = randomNumber(1, 10);
    if(Session["number_x"] != null)
    {
        int number1 = Int.Parse(Session["number_x"]);
        Session["number_x"] = number1 + number2;
    }
    else
    {
        Session["number_x"] = number2;
    }
}
```

Basically, you have to check to see if there's already a value in the session variable.

If there is something already in the session variable, you need to parse it as an `int`, and then add it to the new random number and store it back in the session variable.

If there isn't anything in there, you just need to store the new random number.

Comment: @JeT_BluE Your edit doesn't really change anything about my answer, but thank you for adding the details.

Comment: but you have declared a new int number 1, how does that links to the first generated random number in Page_Load ??

Comment: @JeT_BluE You can't access the number1 declared in Page_Load from Button1_Click, they are not in the same scope.  Your code wouldn't even compile like that, actually.  Thus, I changed it =)

Comment: what if I put number1 in a label and that label should be updated with the new value after the button click ?

Comment: @JeT_BluE You can set the Label on page load, or each time you update Session.  Like this `Label1.Text = Session["number_x"].ToString();`